# Objective-C regular expression string format

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm trying to use the following regular expressions with Objective-C but I can't seem to be able to escape the right characters.  I know I need to escape \ but can't quite get it right.

Can anyone give me any pointers?  I basically just need these in a format Objective-C format.

UK phone

```
^((\(?0\d{4}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|(\(?0\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|(\(?0\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$
```

UK Car reg

```
^([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}$
```

UK Post code

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$
```

Comment: just escape the backslash one more time.

Comment: I've tried escaping the backslash for the uk phone expression giving me the following @"^((\\(?0\\d{4}\\)?\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{3})|(\\(?0\\d{3}\\)?\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{4})|(\\(?0\\d{2}\\)?\\s?\\d{4}\\s?\\d{4}))(\\s?\\#(\\d{4}|\\d{3}))?$" but this did not return a match for a uk phone number.  Any more suggestions?

Comment: A great technique for dealing with strings in iOS/OSX that require escapes is to put them in a text file in your bundle, then read them into your class once (on the first invocation). Now you can write the strings exactly as they should be - works great for JSON too!